# Windows 8 like modal dialog using WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog, prism

I am working on a WPF-MVVM (.Net 4.0) application that has a Metro look (it just has a look, it is not a metro application.)
I need to show a windows 8 like message box that blocks the operations for the user before he rids that message box by clicking yes/no/cancel (or any button.).

I came across this otherwise great [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269364/MVVM-PRISM-Modal-Windows-by-using-Interaction-Requ) and momentarily thought that I have found the solution. But this has its own drawback.It just stops the user from interacting with the controls behind by mouse clicks. The user can however use the tab key to get back to the buttons behind and click them (pressing enter).

A number of things are coming to my mind:

- should I go for custom adorners and play with hitTestable property?
- Or should I place a control and play with its visible property.

Before going for any approach I thought of putting forward my question to the wonderful community here if someone has done a similar thing in past and provide me some pointer/reference/approach.

Can someone suggest what is the way to achieve this? Please note I will be happy to use prism or any other open source if that solves the purpose but the window will have to be custom made.
Please excuse me if you find this too stupid a question. Please pardon my ignorance. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Have a look at ChildWindow in http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home ... you should be able to restyle the "window" to look however you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across a similar problem, I resolved it using a DialogPresenter as explained there:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36516/WPF-Modal-Dialog

I had to do a few tweaks there and there but overall it's working fine and I now have a nice way to display dialog boxes!

Comment: Thanks!! I have just started using this approach in my project. And it seems with little changes this is gonna work!

Comment: FYI the only thing I had to add was a Dispatcher.PushFrame at the beginning so the dialog is "really" modal (otherwise it'd just come as an overlay, leaving your background program running normally)

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way of doing it

```
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Select Social network is already  authorised!");
            dialog.ShowAsync();
```